# Finding and starting a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity C# application where every game inside has one abstract controller. It inherits from another class enabling it to be accessed like a static version of the base behavior in unity.

```
public class AbstractController<T> : SingletonMonoBehavior<T> {
    virtual public void Begin() {
         //startup code here
    }
}
```

So, to find this class, I have to know what T will be. Do I need reflection for this? Or can I just store T types in a List somewhere, and access them dynamically? Right now, I DO have a dictionary of game names and classes that inherit from abstract controllers -- so I know what T is supposed to be, but when I do this:

```
_controllerTypes = new Dictionary<GameScene, Type> ();
_controllerTypes.Add (GameScene.FrogJump, typeof(FJGameController));    
Type T = _controllerTypes [_startScene];
AbstractController<T>[] controllers = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<AbstractController<T>> ();
```

I get a compiler error stating that "The type or namespace name `T' could not be found." Is there a way to design around this? I don't want to use reflection, but I want it to be pretty.

Comment: So you need T's type in-function?

Comment: Added more info to question -- thanks!

Comment: Singeltons and inhertence don't mix well. I would recommend just dropping the `SingletonMonoBehavior<T>` and either use a normal `MonoBehavior` on a object that gets loaded in a pre-load scene or even better use a [`ScriptableObject`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBA1QCoEAX4&list=PLX2vGYjWbI0RtPoeDoBUPnwY8USGra-pD&index=49) to represent the shared state.

Comment: I was hoping to keep SingletonMonoBehavior because all of my controllers, models, and main views already inherit from it, and it's a convenient way to access these things within a game. Any time I need, I can just MyGameController.instance.DoSomething(), whereas if it were a monobehavior, I'd have to create a lot of scaffolding. Do you know of a way around this? I will watch scriptable object video.

Comment: Don't be so abstract that you have to think of using reflection. Try to define your problem better.

Comment: @ChuckSavage Thanks for the advice. It seems to me that my problem is that I want to have a generic way of starting my games -- my current solution to this is to have one class that exists in every scene, and to have that class have other various, helpful functions like "pause". I was also hoping I could just neatly tuck it into my MVC structure, but perhaps I'm just overcomplicating it by thinking so.

Comment: @devRicher See update.

Comment: Catlard, check out interfaces.

Comment: I second what Chuck said. By the way, what does the Dictionary look like? Can you update the question with how `_controllerTypes [_startScene]`  is defined?

Comment: @Programmer Updated. See second code block.

Comment: @ChuckSavage I don't know if interfaces will be all that helpful here. I just read http://www.cjonesdev.com/blog/unity-getcomponentlttgt-and-interfaces -- interfaces allow you to guarantee that a class has a function, but how do you access that class in the first place? You can't just GetComponent for all IControllable interfaces, for example. I'd still have to have an abstract controller class, right?

Comment: You "Know" what class uses the interface you want. IE, define it and stick to your own rules. For example. There is one "Main Camera" per scene. Have that component have your class attached, with a script that uses your interface. Easy to find, easy to use.

Comment: Or look up "dependency injection." There are frameworks that will give you a class object you subscribe to. It is way better than the singleton framework.

Answer (score 0):

What you are about to do is absolutely possible but requires the use of reflection. You shouldn't do this as it will affect the performance of your game. Like *Catlard* mentioned in the comment section, use interface.

> interfaces allow you to guarantee that a class has a function, but how
>   do you access that class in the first place? You can't just
>   GetComponent for all IControllable interfaces, for example. I'd still
>   have to have an abstract controller class, right?

You can use GetComponent to check for an interface.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour, IControllable
{

}
```

then your Interface:

```
public interface IControllable
{

}
```

Now, lets say that your Player script is attached to a GameObject called "Player".

```
GameObject plyrObj = GameObject.Find("Player");

if (plyrObj.GetComponent<IControllable>() != null)
{
    Debug.Log("Player is Controllable");
}
```

Your can also have multiple interface for different classes. You can also make the interface generic with something like `public interface IControllable<T>{}`. This should help you re-do your work.

Comment: Did you try my answer?